# How much video can I store on a pi 3 a+?

Tags: camera, video, storage

I recently got a pi model 3 a+ and a camera module 2.0. I need to store about three hours of video on it. I have a 16gb SD card with raspbian installed. Can someone tell me how much video I can record and store? I would be very grateful.

Comment: how much free space do you have? 2mbit/s compressed video will set you back about 1GB per hour

Comment: Jaromanda X I have 10gb available. I am recording at 720p60. How much could I record?

Comment: are you recording raw video or compressed? if compressed, what bitrate? I've given you enough info regardless of compression ... for 3 hours, you need the video bitrate (in megaBITS per second) * 1.5 GB

Comment: Ok so I could record in raw or bc impressed with lots of space left. Thanks.

Comment: really? raw? I think you miscalculated something - you'd barely get a minute of raw video, even if your sdcard could be written that fast

Comment: Ok, yes I messed up. I can get 3 hours of compressed video on 8 gigs, then?

Comment: well, maybe - 3 hours of 5 megabits per second video will use about 7.5gigs ... I have no way of knowing what bitrate you are using for compression since you've never even hinted that it is compressed - I don't know enough about video in raspberry pi - I assume, since the pi is capable of hardware compression of video that there is some sort of compression possible, but what bitrate you get is probably up to you

Comment: I just googled ... high quality 1080@30 you'd use 10Mbit - you want 720@60 ... using (probably wrong way to do it) very basic maths 10 * 1280 * 720 / 1920 / 1080 - high quality 720@30 would be 4.44Mbits .. but since your framerate is double, for high quality you'd need to use 8.88Mbits ... and that won't fit ... 8.88 since 8.88*1.5 is 13.32 ... given you have 8GB available ... 8/1.5 = 5.333 ... so, if you sacrifice (only a little really) quality, you can set the bitrate to 5300 (the parameter in raspivid at least is in kilobits per second) then it should fit

Comment: I also found a page that states for live streaming 720@60, anything from 3.5 - 5MBits/second is considered optimal so 5.3 should be fine